# Why is my React state undefined even after setting the state in UseEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So this code is getting latitude and longitude passed down from a parent component and then fetching a country code and then fetching news articles based on that country code to pass down to a child. However, when I try to pass the data down I am getting "paper is undefined". Am I setting the state correctly?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { usePosition } from 'use-position';
import Article from './Article';
import './App.css'


const News = (lat, lng) => {

    const API_KEY = `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`
    var url; 
    var newsurl;
    var country;
    const [paper, setPaper] = useState();        

    useEffect(() =>{
        if (typeof lat.lat !== "undefined" && typeof lat.lng !== "undefined"){
            url = `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${lat.lat}%2C${lat.lng}&key=${API_KEY}&pretty=1`
       }   
        async function getCountry(mUrl) {   
            const response = await fetch(mUrl);
            const countryData = await response.json();
            country = countryData.results[0].components["ISO_3166-1_alpha-2"];
            newsurl = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${country.toLowerCase()}&apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`;

            const response2 = await fetch(newsurl);
            const newsData = await response2.json();
            setPaper(newsData);
            //newsData.articles.map((article) => console.log(article.title));
        }

        getCountry(url);
    },[]);
console.log(paper)


return(
        <div>
           {paper.articles.map(article => (
               <Article name={article.title}/>
           )
           )}           

        </div>
    )
}

export default News;
```

Comment: You are missing the variables to pass in dependency array

Comment: it could be because you setPaper as the result of an asynchronous operation but access the paper which could be empty at the time it renders.

Comment: lat.lng and lat.lat is it correct or they should be coord.lat and coord.long (and a single input prop  coord)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first render (before useEffect done) paper is undefined (because you setState without params). So set state like this:

```
 const [paper, setPaper] = useState(null);
```

in the last return (render) try this:

```
 {paper && paper.articles.map(article => ( ....
```

or

```
 {paper ? paper.article.map(... : <WaitComponent/>
```

and rename input props lat, lng with coord and before define first url test:

```
 if (typeof coord.lat !== 'undefined' && typeof coord.lng !== 'undefined')          
{
  url = `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${coord.lat}%2C${coord.lng}&key=${API_KEY}&pretty=1`;
}
```

Comment: I tried using the && and made the state null, the problem now is that React is saying "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.". However, I am passing down a single string not an object so how do I fix this?

Edit: I fixed this problem by de structuring the object prop in the child component